# not able to get foreach data function node js

Tags: node.js

get all forEach result out of foreach.

```
 results.forEach(function(data){
       var fx = require('../lib/money'),
                    oxr = require('open-exchange-rates');
                    // Set App ID (required):
                    oxr.set({
                        app_id: 'd5e619a619bc40e4abdbbf2a1b5a971'
                    });
                    oxr.latest(function(error) {
                        if ( error ) {
                            // `error` will contain debug info if something went wrong:
                            console.log( 'ERROR loading data from Open Exchange Rates API! Error was:' )
                            // Fall back to hard-coded rates if there was an error (see readme)
                            reject(error.toString());
                        }else{
                            // To load rates into the money.js (fx) library for easier currency
                            // conversion, simply apply the rates and base currency like so:
                            fx.rates = oxr.rates;
                            fx.base = oxr.base;

                            // money.js is now initialised with the exchange rates, so this will work:
                            var amount = fx(data.price).from(data.currency).to('INR').toFixed(6);
                            //var obj = {expDetails: exp,convertedCurrency : amount};
                            data.amount  = amount;
                            results.push(data);
                            console.log(results)
                        }

                    });

                });
                resolve(results)
```

console.log(results) printing correct data. but in resolve(results) there is not any push amount data showing?

Comment: Can you update entire method, its unclear here to understand what exactly u are doing here, like what is `fx.rates` and `fx.base` and what is  `oxr.latest(` doing? its returning `error` and nothing else.

Comment: @kgangadhar i am using currency converter. my problem is push data not printing outside of foreach

Comment: `oxr.latest(` is any api call? and how u are getting `fx.rates`?. If you explain it it'll easy to provide answer.

Comment: @kgangadhar updated my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `oxr` api eachtime while looping, You can call `oxr` api once and after getting the `rates` and `price` you can update results data by calculating amount as follows:

```
const fx = require('../lib/money');
const oxr = require('open-exchange-rates');

oxr.set({
    app_id: 'd5e619a619bc40e4abdbbf2a1b5a971'
});

oxr.latest((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('ERROR loading data from Open Exchange Rates API! Error was:')
        reject(error.toString());
    } else {
        fx.rates = oxr.rates;
        fx.base = oxr.base;

        let finalResult = results.reduce((finalResult, data) => {
            let amount = fx(data.price).from(data.currency).to('INR').toFixed(6);
            data['amount'] = amount;
            return [...finalResult, data];
        },[]);
        resolve(finalResult);
    }
});
```